# Custom allocator with compile time array

Tags: c++, memory, atomic, smart-pointers, allocation

I want to have a defined allocation limit (for my µC) to allocate "dynamic" memory.

My code:

```
template<class T, size_t COUNT>
class SimpleAllocator
{
public:
  using value_type = T;

  template<class U>
  struct rebind
  {
    using other = SimpleAllocator<U, COUNT>;
  };

  SimpleAllocator() noexcept
  {
  }

  template<class U, size_t COUNT_U>
  SimpleAllocator(SimpleAllocator<U, COUNT_U> const &other) noexcept
  {
  }

  value_type* allocate(std::size_t p_Count)
  {
    return nullptr;
  }

  void deallocate(value_type* p_Chunk, std::size_t) noexcept
  {
  }

  T m_Chunks[COUNT];
};
```

If I use this allocator with the smart pointer function: **std::allocate_shared** I get an compiler error:

```
error: constructor for 'SimpleAllocator<std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<int, 
  SimpleAllocator<int, 10>, __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy::_S_atomic>, 10>' must
  explicitly initialize the member 'm_Chunks' which does not have a default
  constructor
```

I understand this error but I cannot resolve it. How can I initialize a object like this one:

```
std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<int, SimpleAllocator<int, 10>,
  __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy::_S_atomic>
```

[Live Example.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#%7B%22version%22%3A3%2C%22filterAsm%22%3A%7B%22labels%22%3Atrue%2C%22directives%22%3Atrue%2C%22commentOnly%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22compilers%22%3A%5B%7B%22sourcez%22%3A%22MQSwdgxgNgrgJgUwAQB4IGcAucQHsB8AUKJLIqlnIgGYB0AFkSdPMigLYLu4BOAnkUKYuABygBDYWgnp0SACoAaJOhAAvBAH1MSAMIB5AKoA5eUWjjZSAMoh2YhAEEoUXBEm9CAb0IiYAIygQCAAuQiQkGFUwAHMkADdxWC1MPhFkAF4FAG5CcKRhewkpCytDIgisHhgIHR4Ef3A4fJ8IiKjwONxMegQeJCzbIqcXNw8eFENlAxMzXIiAX1z8oYdnV3dMXgAKAEokMFwEAA8IBBFMFvyFvIjCsUkEaUs5KZV1FL0jU01ylbs1qNNjtVlARhtxpNpt95L98EgILgwFgkAAybq9Hj7Q4nM4XK6LW4JJIwFJpBAAKiQSQhwm2lBCIVUGm0SBEml0uBgYEwuwJbXqmBgPDABxgLguPHmSBu%2BXiuBAcCQiBpYzpiWS2nJVPZuno3IA1soGUyPtpsUdTudLhFWjKifIkOwOfqwAb0ABtGamAC6uSWeXuxSepTkSiQ4B0AEllKGkG9I0gAFLw%2Fy4XBQJC4dI8cYZDLbUHgtW8FDhqPwxHIzCo5RF9YliZvFMIpFYVEW3HW7z5QXC0WYaoIf2B0TB55WcOJmMImSvZSJltpjNZnPjACEBfrQMh5crbZrSGOdYBYIbwKbyhbVfbSD4nat%2BLtfZFSHX22OAyy95HhG3tNLSNlAARgABnhVUIGWRN2HEcA9h7CJxBgLYkGodMBhUbBGUgx5NHQehxHqOAUEjfBtkg5RQN2aUQGoJBtnQ3AvzFCVBz5W18gASBEHhI2obYACIwHFKBaHEwSaOufIECgdAEH5CJeP4oSAFI4EE5QKSYqTCQWIAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22compiler%22%3A%22clang380%22%2C%22options%22%3A%22-std%3Dc%2B%2B11%22%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: And what have you tried to initialize the array? How do you use the allocator class? Can you please show us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Well, my live example (see above) should reach this guideline already. It shows the error in a minimal example. I want to use my *SimpleAllocator* with std::allocate_shared. What information do you else need? The memory location should not be in the data segment and not allocated inside the heap because of the use inside a µC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to initialize any objects in allocator, you just need to allocate memory. So you have to replace this

```
T m_Chunks[COUNT];
```

with for example

```
alignas(T) char m_Chunks[COUNT * sizeof(T)];
```

and update all the bookkeeping (which you haven't shown) accordingly.

That said, having a buffer right inside an allocator itself isn't a good idea (unless you know exactly what you are doing). The allocator is supposed to be a lightweight object, because it's stored by value in containers and is copied during many operations.